# Python pandas regular expression replace part of the matching pattern

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've got a bunch of addresses like so:

```
df['street'] =
    5311 Whitsett Ave 34
    355 Sawyer St
    607 Hampshire Rd #358
    342 Old Hwy 1
    267 W Juniper Dr 402
```

What I want to do is to remove those numbers at the end of the street part of the addresses to get:

```
df['street'] =
    5311 Whitsett Ave
    355 Sawyer St
    607 Hampshire Rd
    342 Old Hwy 1
    267 W Juniper Dr
```

I have my regular expression like this:

```
df['street'] = df.street.str.replace(r"""\s(?:dr|ave|rd)[^a-zA-Z]\D*\d+$""", '', case=False)
```

which gives me this:

```
df['street'] =
    5311 Whitsett
    355 Sawyer St
    607 Hampshire
    342 Old Hwy 1
    267 W Juniper
```

It dropped the words 'Ave', 'Rd' and 'Dr' from my original street addresses. Is there a way to keep part of the regular expression pattern (in my case this is 'Ave', 'Rd', 'Dr' and replace the rest?

**EDIT:**
Notice the address `342 Old Hwy 1`. I do not want to also take out the number in such cases. That's why I specified the patterns ('Ave', 'Rd', 'Dr', etc) to have a better control of who gets changed.

Comment: just use this `r"\s*#?\d+$"` regex

Comment: @AvinashRaj Sorry, I don't understand the suggestion you made. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: try `uu.street.str.replace(r"\s*#?\d+$", '', case=False)`

Comment: in default python, i should use `re.sub(regex, replace, string)`

Comment: Sorry what I don't get is how the pattern you suggested does the job for my situation. I get that \s* matches 0 or more spaces, not sure what "#?" means, then \d+$ is my ending condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    df_street = '''
        5311 Whitsett Ave 34
        355 Sawyer St
        607 Hampshire Rd #358
        342 Old Hwy 1
        267 W Juniper Dr 402
        '''
    # digits on the end are preceded by one of ( Ave, Rd, Dr), space,
    # may be preceded by a #, and followed by a possible space, and by the newline
   df_street = re.sub(r'(Ave|Rd|Dr)\s+#?\d+\s*\n',r'\1\n', df_street,re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE)
print(df_street)

    5311 Whitsett Ave
    355 Sawyer St
    607 Hampshire Rd
    342 Old Hwy 1
    267 W Juniper Dr
```

Comment: Your solution does not keep the 'Ave', 'Rd', or 'Dr' either. I want to keep them.

Comment: That's perfect. `\1` is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> example_str = "607 Hampshire Rd #358"
>>> re.sub(r"\s*\#?[^\D]+\s*$", r"", example_str)
'607 Hampshire Rd'
```